# Event handling in Azure Data Factory

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

Is there any method available in azure data factory to track the events of a pipeline? I have an event log table and I need to log all the events associated with the pipelines into the same table. Any best practice templates /methods available to achieve the same?

Regards,
Sandeep

Comment: hi,any updates here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You could use Azure Monitor in ADF and enable diagnostic log and store the logs into Azure Blob Storage.Then analysis logs and transfer them into tables as you want.

2.Another choice,you could use [ADF monitor SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-programmatically#net) or [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/activityruns/querybypipelinerun) to retrieve the activities run details by `Pipeline Run Id`:

```
List<ActivityRun> activityRuns = client.ActivityRuns.ListByPipelineRun(
resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, runResponse.RunId, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-10), DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10)).ToList(); 
if (pipelineRun.Status == "Succeeded")
    Console.WriteLine(activityRuns.First().Output);
else
    Console.WriteLine(activityRuns.First().Error);
```

Then you could get all the activities details into tables as you want.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @JayGong, we have enabled diagnostics settings and log into Log Analytics.